# USB is not recognized

Tags: usb, malware, antivirus, usb-drive, virus-scanning

[When i connect my it will appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YWDO.jpg)

It shows "The last USB device you connected to the computer malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it"

This error indicates a fundamental failure in the communication between a connected USB device and the Windows operating system. The system detects a device is plugged in, but cannot determine its identity, functionality, or whether it is operating correctly.

This error prevents the connected device from working. It strongly indicates either an issue with the USB device or a communication problem between the device and the operating system.

The error message "USB device not recognized" or "The last USB device you connected to the computer malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it

Comment: This is a question better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) since StackOverflow is primarily for developers and programming related questions